# jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, snapping

I want to know how to clone and append an element to the droppable area with the following code:

```
    $(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".item").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append(ui.draggable);    

            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = width / 2 - ui.draggable.width() / 2;
            var cntrTop = height / 2 - ui.draggable.height() / 2;

            ui.draggable.css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I feel happy if anyone explain me in detail.And please try to give me an example in Fiddle.It helps me a lot.Thank you.

Thank you for your quick response and yes it's fine and when I dragged the clone it's not working and I need to be interchanged the clones I dropped to the nearest location to it.And as you can see in the below mentioned sample it is not draggable when once it is dropped on the target.

http://jsfiddle.net/kiran/brCX5/31/embedded/result/

And the website link is http://www.vitsoe.com/en/re/shop/606/sketchtool where you can see what I mean but in this link it is just attaching but I need it to be dropped ie.. to be snapped to the nearest path and when I dropped with the same image it should attach below to the existing one and not to be overlapped.

And once again thank you for your response.

Thanks for the reply and I need it exactly the same but what happens is that when I interchange the positions as I said before it doesn't snap to the nearest co-ordinates as we first drag and drop on the target and one more thing is that it is adding the images though there is no gap at the end of the div section and if there is no place at the end it should check whether there is gap at the top or bottom and it should append to the the image otherwise it should revert can you please check that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What problem are you having?

Comment: im a little unsure what you want to do

Comment: welcome to the community, please take some time to read through the [StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: when you want to reply to someone you can leave a comment on their answer. Usually this requires a higher reputation, but since you asked the question you can reply to anyone. Don't edit the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/brCX5/33/

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        snap: '.ui-droppable',
        snapMode: 'outer'
    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            $(this).append(clone);
            clone.removeClass('draggable')
            clone.draggable({
                snap: '.ui-droppable',
                snapMode: 'outer'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Works like a charm :-), your welcome

Comment: Neal this does not seem to work, it puts block under in some occasions.

Comment: @Marino what seems to be the issue that warranted a -1?

Comment: Block get put out of the column if you drag and drop them on the first block in the column.

Comment: Well not exactly, it is working erratically. SOmetimes yes sometimes no :/

Comment: @Marino, i am not sure what that means